# R. How to boost the SVM model

Tags: r

I have made SVM model using SVM package in R for a classification problem. I got only 87% accuracy. But random forest produces around 92.4%.

```
fit.svm<-svm(modelformula, data=training, gamma = 0.01, cost = 1,cross=5)
```

Would like to use boosting for tuning this SVM model. Can someone will help me to tune this SVM model?

1. What are the best parameters I can provide for SVM method?
2. Example for booting for SVM model.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question.

- The e1071 library in R has a built-in tune() function to perform CV. This will help you select the optimal parameters cost, gamma, kernel. You can also manipulate a SVM in R with the package kernlab. You may get different results from the 2 libraries. Let me know if you need any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) package. It allows you to both pick various kernels for SVM ([model list](http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html)) and also run parameter sweeps to find the best model.